# Metrics on n-sphere

Tags: metric-spaces, spheres

What are some common metrics on an n-sphere $S = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : ||x||_2 = 1 \} $ ?

I think that the angle between vectors is a metric on $S$. What other common metrics are there? Citations also welcome.

Background: I have an estimation algorithm which theoretically works for any metric. However, in practice some metrics may have additional properties which I may be able to make use of algorithmically (e.g. for faster computation). However, the vector-angle-metric is the only one I know of.

Comment: I would think that the geodesic distance or the induced metric from $\mathbb{R}^n$ are the most common options. Every rotationally invariant option is a monotonic function of either of these (or the angle metric).

Comment: Yes the subspace metric is an obvious one, but which I still did not think about. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, the geodesic distance is just a multiple of the angle, neato.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are surprisingly few sensible choices to consider. Symmetry considerations motivate any metric $d(x,\,y)$ reduce to one on the centre-$O$ circle passing through $x,\,y$, and further to some function of the angle $\theta\in[0,\,\pi]$ between them, which lies in that circle's plane. The most obvious options are the arc length $\theta$ (which you cited) and the chord length $\sqrt{2(1-\cos\theta)}=2\sin\tfrac{\theta}{2}$.

Comment: Hmm.. Can you make it more precise what you mean by symmetry considerations? How does the reduction work?

Comment: @kaba Say I mark two points on the $n$-sphere, then rotate it around $O$. Should the "distance" between the marks, which move in the process, change? If it could, what would it really mean to say how much distance there is between those points?

Comment: That is to say, the metric should be rotationally invariant? Is that coming from the thinking of the sphere as a Riemannian manifold? (I have little knowledge on them). My algorithm is using non-rotationally-invariant metrics (e.g. max-norm induced) on $\mathbb{R}^n$, so they may be relevant too.

Comment: @kaba I'd only advise such metrics if you're happy to privilege some coordinate system.

Comment: That may well be good advice.